# Método eliminar con Dispersión en c++ (Hashing Table)

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con el método de eliminar en Dispersión mi código de eliminar es el siguiente:

```
void Empleados::Eliminar(){
  int i,band=0,opcion,posanterior;
  cout << ":::Eliminar Empleado:::" << endl;
  cout << "Ingresa el nombre del empleado: ";
  cin.getline(llave,35);
  fstream a("Chambamex.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
  if(!a.good()){
    cout << "Archivo Chambamex no encontrado" << endl;
    system("pause");
  }else{
      Dispersion();
      cout<<"BASE: "<<d_base<<endl;
      d_base=d_base*((sizeof(x)*4)+sizeof(int));
      a.seekg(d_base,ios::beg);
      a.read((char*)&cont,sizeof(int));
      for(i=0;i<cont;i++){
          a.read((char*)&x,sizeof(x));
          if(strcmpi(llave,nombre)==0){
              band=1;
              cout << "========================" << endl;
              cout << "Informacion del empleado" << endl;
              cout << "========================" << endl;
              cout << "Nombre: " << nombre << endl;
              cout << "Domicilio: " << domicilio << endl;
              cout << "Ciudad: " << ciudad << endl;
              cout << "Telefono: " << telefono << endl;
              cout << "Correo electronico: " << correo << endl;
              cout << "========================" << endl;
              cout << "Deseas eliminar este empleado" << endl;
              cout << "========================" << endl;
              cout << "[1]Si" << endl;
              cout << "[0]No" << endl;
              cout << "========================" << endl;
              cout << "Ingresa tu opcion: ";
              cin>>opcion;
              switch(opcion){
                case 0:
                  break;
                case 1:
                  a.seekp(d_base,ios::beg);
                  a.write((char*)&x,sizeof(x));
                  cout << "Empleado eliminado correctamente" << endl;
                  system("pause");
                  break;
                default:
                  cout<<"El numero de opcion escrito no es valido"<<endl;
                  system("pause");
              }
            }
          }
      if(band==0)
    cout<<"No se encontro el registro, intente de nuevo";
  }
 a.close();
}
```

El problema es que si tengo un dato registrado lo ingreso y según lo elimina, al momento de mostrarlo me hace un bucle infinito y todo se muestra vacío pero lo muestra indefinidamente. No se si el problema este en el mostrar o el eliminar. Mi método de dispersión es el siguiente:

```
void Empleados::Dispersion(){
  int j=0;
  d_base=0;
  while(j<strlen(llave)){
      d_base=d_base+(100*llave[j])+(llave[j+1]%84645);
      j=j+2;
  }
 d_base=d_base%100;
}
```

Y mi método mostrar es el siguiente:

```
void Empleados::Mostrar(){
  int i;
  pos=0;
  ifstream a("Chambamex.txt");
  if(!a.good()){
    cout<<"No existe el archivo";
  }
  else{
    cout << ":::Mostrando Empleados:::" << endl;
    cout << "========================" << endl;
    while(!a.eof()){
        a.seekg(pos,ios::beg);
        a.read((char*)&cont,sizeof(int));
        if(cont==0){
        pos=pos+(4*sizeof(x))+sizeof(int);
        }else{
            for(i=0;i<cont;i++){
                a.read((char*)&x,sizeof(x));
                cout << "Nombre: " << nombre << endl;
                cout << "Domicilio: " << domicilio << endl;
                cout << "Ciudad: " << ciudad << endl;
                cout << "Telefono: " << telefono << endl;
                cout << "Correo electronico: " << correo << endl;
                cout << "========================" << endl;
            }
            pos=pos+(4*sizeof(x))+sizeof(int);
        }
    }
   system("pause");
  }
 a.close();
}
```

Quiero saber si el método eliminar lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta o que me puedan orientar de qué forma se puede eliminar el dato con el Método de Dispersión(Hashing Table).

Comment: Cuál se supone que ha de ser la acción al borrar un usuario? Tu al borrar estás creando un duplicado

Comment: @eferion eso es lo que quiero saber amigo, si es que lo estoy haciendo de manera errónea. Investigue un poco y encontré algunos ejemplos donde lo hacían de esa forma y corrias el programa ese de ejemplo y elimina bien sin problemas, mas no se en mi caso cual seria la forma correcta de poder eliminar el dato.

Comment: Eliminar un registro puede hacerse de varias maneras: dejando una id no válida o el registro en blanco o reescribiendo el resto del fichero. Las dos primeras formas son más rápidas de programar pero el fichero no decrece de tamaño, mientras que en la última te garantizas que solo hay registros validos... ¿que opción es la que tienes que implementar?

Comment: Me gustaría utilizar la segunda porque solo se queda con registrados válidos, aunque la primera no suena tan mal. Pero si me quedo con la segunda opción.

Comment: Necesitas elaborar un planteamiento claro y conciso de tu problema. En el código que nos muestras, existen multitud de variables desconocidas para el lector (x, llave, d_base, etc.) y otros elementos que dificultan la legibilidad y no aportan nada a la resolución del problema (por ejemplo tantos cout). ¿Puedes por favor elaborar un ejemplo [MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Si lees bien te das cuenta que llave es el dato que pides, d_base aparece en el método dispersión y x es el que maneja toda la clase. Pero si replanteare la pregunta de forma más adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

antes que nada, Hassem cierto?
Me parece que el problema es que tu muestras basado en lo que el contador te dice, es decir, lees el contador y 
si este tiene un valor de 3 sabes que debes leer 3 objetos. Mostrar() esta bien, sin embargo una vez que tratas de eliminar

```
a.seekp(d_base,ios::beg);
a.write((char*)&x,sizeof(x));
```

Aqui lo que estas haciendo es regresarte hasta la posicion que te dijo el metodo dispersion 
y estas sobreescibiendo a partir de donde esta guardado el contador, lo cual me imagino es lo que causa el error que describes.
Ahora lo que se supone debes hacer basado en tu codigo es disminuir el contador

```
a.seekp(d_base,ios::beg);
cont--;
a.write((char*)&cont,sizeof(int));
```

una vez hecho esto, falta lo dificil ya que notaras que si estabas buscando un elemento que estaba en la segunda de tus cuatro posiciones y tu tienes
todas las posiciones ocupadas el contador que estaba en 4 quedaria en 3 y al mostrar solo te mostraria los primeros tres por lo cual 
el cuarto elemento quedaria inaccesible y el segundo se seguiria mostrando ya que no se eliminó, aqui lo que debes hacer es que una vez 
que encuentres el elemento a eliminar, revises si hay mas elementos despues de ese y los recorras, osea que si eliminas el segundo elemento
y el tercero y cuarto elemento ya estan capturados, los recorres, de modo que el tercero sobreesciba al segundo y el cuarto al tercero
y posteriormente disminuyes el contador.
Como se supone que no debemos dar toda la respuesta no te pongo el codigo, intentalo asi y si tienes dudas pues aqui estamos para apoyar

Comment: Hola, no no es de Hassem aunque si la actividad que nos dieron a realizar si está creada por el. De hecho ya logre realizar todo porque tuve que recorrer los elementos para poder decrementar el contador y que el último elemento quedará inaccesible. Y respecto a tu respuesta claro que puedes poner la porcion de codigo que me puede ayudar a explicar mi pregunta. De igual forma como te mencione ya lo realize, aun asi agradezco tu respuesta.